# Understanding how Fascism showed that direct government is not same as self-government

Tags: political-theory, direct-democracy, fascism

Harold Joseph Laski in his book **Parliamentary Government in England** writes:

> Direct government, in short, is not the same thing as self-government; it may, indeed, as the experience of Fascist countries has shown, be the exact antithesis of it.

How did Fascist countries in 1930s (as the book was published in 1938) show that direct government is opposite of self-government? The concepts of direct government and self government are democratic ones, but Fascism was a supporter of dictatorial kind of government, the two most famous Fascists: Adolf Hitler and Benito Mussolini were dictators.

Why did Harold J. Laski choose the example of Fascist countries for explaining that concept of direct government vs self government? Is there a very evident relationship between direct government and Fascism?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take these loose understandings of Laski's concepts:

- **Self-government:** the ability of a group — a church, a trade union, an ethnic community — to establish rules for itself independent of (and free from interference by) the overarching state. The First Amendment of the US constitution (e.g.) effectively lays out certain principles of self-government for religions, the press, and associations of citizens
- **Direct government:** A system whereby groups of citizens can influence or dictate the practices of the state through plebiscite or other forms of mass-public action. Several US states (e.g.) have [ballot initiative](https://ballotpedia.org/Ballot_initiative) systems where citizens of the state can vote directly on legislation, bypassing state legislatures.

Laski's issue is that *direct government* often becomes a tool used by activated groups to suppress or destroy the *self-government* of other groups. He points at fascism because fascists invariably leverage the power of direct government to disempower and disenfranchise everyone outside their ethnocultural group. Self-government decentralizes power in society; direct government centralizes power.

It's deeply misleading to make a claim like:

> The concept(s) of direct government and self government are democratic
> [...], but Fascism [is dictatorial]

Fascism is a corrupt or malignant form of democracy: the perfected form of group tyranny within democratic systems. The logic of a fascist group always follows the same course:

1. Extoll the virtues of democratic rights and liberties as the highest ideals of humanity
2. Decry how 'other' (outsider) groups have weakened, destroyed, or stolen the democratic rights and liberties of 'our' (fascist) group
3. Demand publicly that 'our' (fascist) group must band together to take control to restore 'our' democratic rights and liberties, weeding out those 'others' as one would weed out parasites or vermin

Fascism cannot exist outside of a democratic political system any more than cancer can exist outside of a living organism, and for much the same reason. Fascism is a disease of liberal democracy, a disease that co-opts the principles and systems of liberal democracy to destroy it from within.

Comment: While these are some good points, "dictatorship of the majority" is not something that Laski brings up in that context though. His explicit beef is only with referendums. (And since he otherwise endorsed a Marxist/Communist revolution... it's not clear he would have agreed that "dictatorship of the proletariat" would have been a bad thing,.. unlike Fascism.)

Comment: @Fizz: I didn't say "dictatorship of the majority:; I said "group tyranny". that group could be the majority; it could be a minority; it could be a group that believes it *ought* to be the majority. Don't read stuff into what I said.

Comment: Looking through https://www.jstor.org/stable/41855919, Laski for instance argued (post 1930 or so) that dictatorship was justifiable or at least unavoidable in the Soviet Union, since the Western powers were trying to overthrow Communism there. 
(Prior to 1925 he held a much more critical view, but the suppression of the general strike in England in 1926-7 and the Great Depression pushed him to be much more willing to endorse violent means as at least unavoidable.)

Comment: I upvoted this, but I wonder, doesn't Communism do much the same thing?  I'm thinking of what happened at the start of the Soviet Union.  They extol the virtues of democratic rights for the proletariat, decry the influence of capitalism and reactionary elements, then demand weeding them out.  I suppose these might just be similar tactics used towards different ends.

Comment: @Ryan_L: Unbeknownst to most, Maxism is in actuality an evolute of Liberal philosophy (not something separate and opposed) so it shares some of the same basic weaknesses. But where Liberal democracy is prone to fascism (a form of ethnonationalism in which an aggrieved subgroup tries to present itself as the entire 'proper' body politic), Marxist systems are pone to totalitarian socialism (a form of statism that tries to control and structure the lives of all people that live within its territory). Both tendencies are bad, but bad for different reasons in different ways...

Comment: That sounds VERY U.S. centric. Like "self-government" is the ability of a group to govern themselves. Like Laski mentions colonial India which largely did not posses that ability. There's no overarching state in that picture and an external overarching state is somewhat antithetical to self-governance or an expression of self-governance itself. And no Laski's problem with direct government is not a tyranny of a majority concept but he's conceptually opposed to ripping one issue out of it's context making it more of a means for general feedback than a productive interaction.

Comment: Also while Nazis used plebiscites in their rise to power, they were, afaik, largely ineffective to produce any legal change. They were rather used as a means to gather popular support, as Laski has said, they were more of a means to express a general feedback than a particular well informed proposal. The central and decentralized approach is largely not prioritized outside of the U.S.

Comment: And no the Nazis did not extoll the virtues of democracy and civil liberties. This would be a facet of U.S. based fascism, but Germany had it's first republic in 1918 so it didn't have a republic and a fond tradition of democracy and civil liberties that politicians could draw from. Instead the conservatives rejected democracy and preferred authoritarian rule and the socialists thought the parliamentary system wasn't democratic enough. So Hitler was openly antidemocratic calling it a plutocracy a jewish invention arguing that the democratic countries are the enemies and so on.

Comment: @TedWrigley [4/5] 2. and 3. are still valid and afaik often called "Palingenetic ultranationalism" the "WE were great, THEY [scapegoat] have brought us down but we are destined to rise again". But you don't need democracy for that. Both Hitler and Mussolini went for authoritarian Empires as their "former great" rather than any liberal concept. They instead obviously showed their support for elitist ideas and top-down collectivism. Apart from the "paradox of tolerance" there's really no good argument for this Marxist reading of fascism as an extension of liberal democracy, is it?

Comment: @TedWrigley [5/5]  Both Lenin and Hitler didn't actually count on the support of the masses but of an "specially trained minority" exposing elitist rather than democratic ideas and both went on to secure power outside of a popular mandate rather than as a populist dictator. They also both created a totalitarian system where the ideology tried to get into every possible niche or rather where the dictatorial control reaches everywhere. So while ideologically very far away from each other, in terms of getting power and holding power they were pretty similar.

Comment: @haxor789:  It's easy to miss the forest for the trees — to miss the nuance among a slew of particularities — and so I going to address your posts briefly and generally. First, I think you've confused Lenin and Stalin. Lenin was an idealist, and committed (in his way) to Marxist egalitarianism; Stalin converted Lenin's socialist idealism into an authoritarian surveillance state. Lenin clearly did count on the support of the masses to embrace the ideals and work towards Marxist notions of the 'Good Society', even to the extent of reeducating those who clung to capitalism or royalism.

Comment: @haxor789: A Stalin cannot come to power except under the idealism of something like Leninism, by corrupting the state apparatus that s supposed to be a servant of the masses. A Hitler cannot come to power except under the idealism of a democratic republic (like the Weimar Republic), by corrupting democratic institutions and their implicit demand for mutual respect. The roads to power are different, even if the end results are similar.

Comment: @haxor789: And note that even at their height, Stalinism and Fascism were not *that* similar. Stalinism was brooding and introspective: focused on controlling the masses under their thumb without much discrimination. Fascism was aggressive and expansive, aiming to upshot the 'wrong' people for the benefit of the 'right' people. Stalinism took wealth and industry from everyone and gave it to the state; Fascism took wealth and industry from non-aryans and gave it as private ownership to aryans. The different ideals they corrupted still colored their manifestation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142655/discussion-between-haxor789-and-ted-wrigley).

Answer (score 3):

That pronouncement of Laski comes at the end of para/section in which he rails against referendums. Basically Laski argues that the rise of Fascism has shown that referendums ask meaningless questions and deceive the electorate, so they are fake democracy. The rest is just idiosyncratic use of terms. Before talking of Fascism, he argues that even in better circumstances the general public is incapable of really voting on the issue at hand in a referendum, and instead just passes general judgement on the government in such referenda anyway.

(Laski [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Laski) also basically a Communist, and he thought that the right solution to most political issues was for workers to rise in a violent revolution.)

Answer (score 1):

Laski moved from democratic and constitutional pluralism to Marxism after the experience of the Great Depression which revealed to him the inherent inability of capitalist society to work for the common good. In no way was he a revolutionary communist calling for the violent overthrow of established governmemt.

In his foreword to Brady's book on Hitler's regime, he stated that in his view, the motive behind the the Nazi system was to extend and enforce upon the whole nation:

> The rules, the behaviour patterns, and the points of view of the ordinary autocratically governed business enterprise

And

> Fascism is nothing other than monopoly capitalism imposing its will on the masses whom it as deliberately transformed onto its slaves.

Moreover, the fascist philosopher Giovanni Gentile in 1928 described the relationship between freedom and the state as:

> Freedom can only exist within the State, and the State means authority. But the State is not some entity hovering in the air above the heads of its citizens. It is one with the personality of the citizen.

And:

> the need of the Party, and all the instruments of propaganda and education with which Fascism seeks to make the thought and will of the Duce the thought and will of the masses.

Moreover:

> the need of the Party, and all the instruments of propaganda and education with which Fascism seeks to make the thought and will of the Duce the thought and will of the masses.

It's most likely this notion of control of the population he is referring to through the instruments of propaganda including those of what looks like direct democracy but actually disguises the control of the fascist hierarchy.

It's worth recalling here that Hitler and the Nazi party took power by democratic means.

Laski is not discussing here the classic notion of direct democracy practised in the ancient greek city-state given that European states are of such a size that makes direct democracy a practical impossibility but how democracy itself can be suborned into a fascistic policy whilst all the time fascist propaganda is saying it is making a more 'direct' and purer democracy possible.

Comment: The Nazi party did not take power by democratic means. When the Nazis increased in popularity the legitimacy for the government had already moved from public mandate to emergency decrees of the president. i.e. a government is appointed, gets a vote of no confidence from parliament and stays in office till the next election and even with the abuse of executive powers to meddle in the next election Hitler still only scored a plurality and went on to seize power by banning and coercing the other parties to pass an emergency decree to make himself a de facto dictator. Democracy was already dead